# Не запускается ф-я javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть файл scroll.js, в нем идет ф-я:

```
(function($) {
...
}(jQuery));
```

[Полный исходник файла scroll.js](http://dev.skins4dimes.com/js/scroll.js)

Есть файл main.php:

```
<script>
$('#demo5').scrollbox({
    direction: 'h',
    distance: 134,
    linear: true,
    //step: 10,
    delay: 0,
    speed: 0
}); </script>
```

[Полный исходник файла maine.php](http://dev.skins4dimes.com/ajax/roulette.php)

Указанный выше код работает корректно.

Мне нужно вызвать контент файла main.php в событии onclick. Для этого я заключил контент этого файла в ф-ю:

```
function csgo() {

    $('#demo5').scrollbox({
        direction: 'h',
        distance: 134,
        linear: true,
        //step: 10,
        delay: 0,
        speed: 0
    }); 
}
```

Вызываю эту функцию так:

```
<div onclick="csgo();">start</div>
```

Если вызывать просто

```
function csgo() { 
    alert('Good');
}
```

- он выполняется !

И вот незадача ! Не работает ! Просто ничего не работает. Подскажите в чем ошибка?

Comment: можно например вызывать функцию: `csgo()`

Comment: смотри ошибки в консоли браузера. Ну и нужно больше кода: пока могу только предположить что либо `csgo` объявлена после этого элемента, либо такой функции вообще нет, либо что-то еще

Comment: @Grundy Консоль браузера вывела вот такую ошибку http://prntscr.com/936i83

Comment: данная ошибка говорит. что `scrollbox` не добавлен в jQuery, а значит на момент вызывания `csgo` не выполнился код из `scroll.js` он мог не выполниться, если, например, не подключен в _main.php_

Comment: @Grundy Добавил исходники файлов в посте. Все подключено (по моему).

Comment: что-то я не вижу проблемы файлах по ссылке: при запуске `startt` никаких ошибок нет, все крутится. Где вот этот код: `<div onclick="csgo();">start</div>`?

Comment: @Grundy Здесь http://freetexthost.com/fcpdjhyiac Строка <button class="start-game" data-id="<?=$res['id'];?>" id="start_game" onclick="startt();">Открыть кейс</button>

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31618/discussion-between-slavik-okara-and-grundy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в подключении двух разных версий jquery.

P.S.: спасибо @Grundy.